# cant override method in a base class with my code

Tags: python

```
   class Vehicle():

        def __init__(self, brand, model):

            print('Am a vehicle')

        def brand_name(self, brand):
            print('vehicle class')
            self.brand = brand
            return brand


        def Vehicle_model(self, model):
            print('vehicle class')

            self.model = model
            return model


     class Mazda(Vehicle):
            def __init__(self, model, brand):



            Vehicle.__init__(self,brand, model)

            def brand_name(self, brand):
                print('base class method')
                self.brand = brand
                print(brand +" " +'is a good brand')

            def Vehicle_model(self, model):
                print('base class method')
                self.model = model
                print('i am a '+ ' '+ self.model +''+self.brand+"model") 


     maz = Mazda(2019,'camry')   
     output>>>   Am a vehicle

     maz.brand_name('Toyota')
     output>>> vehicle class
     output>>  'Toyota'
```

i want override the method in the base class  but when i try using the derived class object to call the method inside the derived class, it not working to my expectation. i expect the derived class methods to be executed not the base class, please guys what am i doing wrong

Comment: `Vehicle.__init__(self,brand, model)` has the same indent level like previous line. Is this a typo?

Comment: I don't think this code snippet you put runs. All function declarations need a body and you don't have one for Mazda's `__init__` rn (unless the next line is part of the function body). The compiler should be complaining. You really need to fix the indentations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class Vehicle():

```
    def __init__(self, brand, model):

        print('Am a vehicle')

    def brand_name(self, brand):
        print('vehicle class')
        self.brand = brand
        return brand


    def Vehicle_model(self, model):
        print('vehicle class')

        self.model = model
        return model


 class Mazda(Vehicle):
        def __init__(self, model, brand):
            Vehicle.__init__(self,brand, model)  # your problem was here wrong indentation

        def brand_name(self, brand):
            print('base class method')
            self.brand = brand
            print(brand +" " +'is a good brand')

        def Vehicle_model(self, model):
            print('base class method')
            self.model = model
            print('i am a '+ ' '+ self.model +''+self.brand+"model")
```

do well and check your indentation, that seems to be the problem, `Vehicle.__init__(self,brand, model)` was not indented well. hope it helps

Comment: yeah thanks a lot I over looked that the interpreter didn't complain, so I never look at that code thanks ..

Answer (score 1):

Try the code after proper indentation:

```
class Vehicle():

    def __init__(self, brand, model):

        print('Am a vehicle')

    def brand_name(self, brand):
        print('vehicle class')
        self.brand = brand
        return brand


    def Vehicle_model(self, model):
        print('vehicle class')

        self.model = model
        return model


class Mazda(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, model, brand):
        Vehicle.__init__(self,brand, model)

    def brand_name(self, brand):
        print('base class method')
        self.brand = brand
        print(brand +" " +'is a good brand')

    def Vehicle_model(self, model):
        print('base class method')
        self.model = model
        print('i am a '+ ' '+ self.model +''+self.brand+"model") 


maz = Mazda(2019,'camry')

maz.brand_name('Toyota')
```

It is working fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can see my problem now